# Redirect to different page after session expires

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-security, spring-webflow

I have a web application build with these technologies :

- Spring MVC
- Web Flow
- Spring Security
- Primefaces

And I need to redirect user to different page after session expires. After some research I found two options. Use JavaScript with timeout function or `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` tag.
But is there some more elegant way to do it ?

I also tried to do it with HttpSessionListener but I didn't know how to redirect client to different site (I am not sure if it is possible).

Or would it be possible to configure Tomcat  or Apache to somehow refresh clients view after some time ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to implement a filter:
1) Check for [HttpServletRequest.getRequestedSessionId()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestedSessionId%28%29), if it returns `null` it is a fresh request else there was an active session before.
2) Check for [HttpServletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isRequestedSessionIdValid%28%29), if it returns `false` it would mean that the session had been expired on the server side.
3) Redirect from filter, if required.

Comment: I am not quit sure what do you mean. Could you be more specific.

Comment: It will not be ideally possible to redirect user as soon as the session times out on the server. However on the very next request for the user, you can check for session validity and redirect to login/some other page.

Comment: It would be good if you can do it in the security filter itself but since I have not used spring security before. I do not know of its flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I use to notify user about session expiration and redirect user to 'you have been logged out' page:

```
   <h:form prependId="false" style="display:none;">
      <p:idleMonitor
         timeout="#{session.maxInactiveInterval * 1000 - 60000}"
         onidle="startIdleMonitor()"
         onactive="timeoutDialog.hide()" />

      <p:dialog id="timeoutSession"
         header="Session expiring..."
         widgetVar="timeoutDialog"
         showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade"
         modal="true"
         closable="false"
         draggable="false"
         resizable="false"
         appendToBody="true"
         position="center"
         onHide="stopCount()"
         onShow="doTimer()">
         <br />
         <p>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 8px 8px 0;"/>
            <p:panel>
               Your session will expire in&nbsp;
               <span id="dialog-countdown" style="font-weight: bold"></span>
               &nbsp;seconds
            </p:panel>
         </p>
         <br/>
         <p style="font-weight: bold;">Please move your mouse to keep the session alive</p>
      </p:dialog>
      <p:remoteCommand name="keepAlive" actionListener="#{applicationBean.keepSessionAlive}" />
   </h:form>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var TIME = 60; // in seconds
      var countTimer = TIME;
      var processTimer;
      var timer_is_on = 0;
      var redirectPage = "#{applicationBean.logoutURL}";

      var countDownDiv = "dialog-countdown";
      var txtCountDown = null;
      if (!txtCountDown)
        txtCountDown = document.getElementById(countDownDiv);

      function startIdleMonitor() {
        countTimer = TIME;
        txtCountDown.innerHTML = countTimer;
        timeoutDialog.show();
      }
      function timedCount() {
        txtCountDown.innerHTML = countTimer;
        if (countTimer == 0) {
            stopCount();
            window.location.href = redirectPage;
            return;
        }
        countTimer = countTimer - 1;
        processTimer = setTimeout("timedCount()", 1000);
      }
      function doTimer() {
        if (!timer_is_on) {
            timer_is_on = 1;
            timedCount();
        }
      }
      function stopCount() {
        clearTimeout(processTimer);
        timer_is_on = 0;
        keepAlive();
      }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good idea to make sure that the application is handling all 3 three cases (login failure, invalid session and expired session). One way to do that in spring security is as follows:

```
    <http>
...
<!-- form login if you have one -->
<form-login authentication-failure-url="/handleLoginFailure" />
     ...
     <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrentSessionFilter" />
<session-management invalid-session-url="/handleSessionNoLongerActive" session-authentication-strategy-ref="concurrentSessionControlStrategy" />

</http>



<beans:bean id="concurrentSessionFilter" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter" 
    c:sessionRegistry-ref="sessionRegistry" 
    c:expiredUrl="/handleSessionExpired">
</beans:bean>


@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    SessionRegistryImpl impl = new SessionRegistryImpl() ;
    return impl;
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy concurrentSessionControlStrategy() {
    ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy impl = new ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy(sessionRegistry()) ;
    return impl;
}
```

Also see [Session Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/session-mgmt.html). (web.xml changes).

Depending on the application functionality, you might also need to handle access-denied situation.